# Have some problems with my first EC2 virtual server (AWS) - I can't create a new file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

**1.** I was using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNr7YqjjzOY

**2.** I installed my first EC2 based on Ubuntu:

[image]

**3.** I connected via ssh:

[image]

---

**But I can't add a new file or edit existing files:**

[image]

**Shall I use any additional things? By the way, I have the same problem in WinSCP.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo bash
echo "test" > test.html
```

Of course, this is just for testing.

Comment: Sorry @BohdanVorona, I have just tested it and edited my answer above. This one should work. Of course, this is not the way to go, the point is mainly, that you don't have rights writing in /var/www/html (I assume, at least it's ok for my box now)

Comment: Thanks. The second variant is working. But I have the same problem in WinSCP. Do you any suggestions about that?

Comment: For WinSCP I've found the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/286831/how-do-i-copy-files-into-var-www-with-winscp

marco, thank you!

Comment: @Marco, you're getting permission denied because that folder does not have write permissions for your username.  Change the ownership with sudo chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html (which I would not recommend) or  permissions with sudo chmod -R o+rwx /var/www/.